# Need help using chrome.webRequest to block a website using a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been working on an extension for some time, and I encountered a problem...
I made a button to toggle the blocking of the website, using this code:

```
$('#togglesafety').click(function(){
        chrome.storage.sync.get(['toggle'],function(website){

            var newTotal = "";
            if(!(website.toggle)){
                newTotal = "Enabled";
            }
            else{
                if(website.toggle == "Enabled"){
                    newTotal = "Disabled";
                }
                else{
                    newTotal = "Enabled";
                }
            }
            chrome.storage.sync.set({'toggle': newTotal}, function(){},)
            $('#toggled').text(newTotal);
        });
    });
```

And then blocking a list of blacklisted websites using this code:

```
const blockedWebsitesUrl = [
    "https://*.example.com/*"
]

chrome.storage.sync.get(["toggle"],function(website){
    if(website.toggle == "Enabled") {
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(     
            function(details) {
                return {cancel: true};
            },
            {urls: blockedWebsitesUrl},
            ["blocking"]
        );
    }
    else {
        //
    }
})
```

But the problem is that if I refresh the extension while having the blocking enabled, when I change change it, it doesn't change until the next refresh.
Can anyone help me understand how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the webRequest listener a named global function so its reference will be persistent and re-register it when the storage is changed:

```js
const blocker = {
  toggle: null,
  urls: [],
  listener() {
    return {cancel: true};
  },
};

function registerBlocker(toggle = blocker.toggle, urls = blocker.urls) {
  blocker.toggle = toggle;
  blocker.urls = urls;
  chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(blocker.listener);
  if (toggle === 'Enabled' && urls.length) {
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(blocker.listener, {urls},
      ['blocking']);
  }
},

chrome.storage.sync.get(['toggle', 'urls'], data => {
  registerBlocker(data.toggle, data.urls);
});

chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(({ toggle, urls }) => {
  if (toggle || urls) {
    registerBlocker(toggle?.newValue, urls?.newValue);
  }
});
```